# Show spelling suggestions when StackEdit.io spell checker says word is wrong

Tags: spell-check

I am writing a document in Google Drive (I still call it Google Docs) using the [StackEdit.io editor](https://stackedit.io/).

I have Google Chrome's spell checker disabled. StackEdit.io provides one and I like it that way. Misspelled words are underlined, but sometimes I can't figure out my mistake (English is not my mother tongue).

[image: stackedit showing typo]

Is there a way in StackEdit.io to show the spelling suggestions for a misspelled word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the developer.

It supposed to work, but it's pretty buggy, on Chrome particularly. There is an [open issue on GitHub](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/issues/273) about that and on [ACE repo as well](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/1785).

As a workaround, you can use the "Light mode" (Settings>Advanced) which will replace the ACE editor by a textarea.

Comment: Great ! Keep up the good work, I love StackEdit !